# Use of hdf5 library in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, hdf5

I would like to use `hdf5` library directly from `Python` with `ctypes`. I know that `h5py` and `PyTables` do the job perfectly. The reason I want to do this: I need to work with `hdf5` files with a `Python` interpreter where I can not install any package.

I am looking for an example that creates a file and write a list of doubles.

So far, I have written

```
from ctypes import *
hdf5Lib=r'/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.dylib'
lib=cdll.LoadLibrary(hdf5Lib)
major = c_uint()
minor = c_uint()
release = c_uint()
lib.H5get_libversion(byref(major), byref(minor), byref(release))
H5Fopen=lib.H5Fopen
...
```

I don't know how to call H5Fopen. Should I use `H5Fopen.argtypes`? Any advice is welcome is to open the hdf5 file, create a dataset that of doubles, write the data and close the file.

Comment: 'I need to work with hdf5 files with a Python interpreter where I can not install any package.' I never quite get these scenarios. If you are allowed to type text into a text editor and save it, how come you cannot copy-paste the relevant python eggs to your working directory? Seems like a much simpler solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the advices given, and I have written a small C program to discover the value of different macros.

```
#include "hdf5.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("H5F_ACC_TRUNC  = %u\n",H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    printf("H5P_DEFAULT    = %u\n",H5P_DEFAULT);
    printf("H5T_STD_I32LE  = %u\n",H5T_STD_I32LE);
    printf("H5T_STD_I32BE  = %i\n",H5T_STD_I32BE);
    printf("H5T_NATIVE_INT = %u\n",H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    printf("H5S_ALL        = %u\n",H5S_ALL);
    return 0;
}
```

which produce

```
H5F_ACC_TRUNC  = 2
H5P_DEFAULT    = 0
H5T_STD_I32LE  = 50331712
H5T_STD_I32BE  = 50331713
H5T_NATIVE_INT = 50331660
H5S_ALL        = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to define argtypes as `H5Fopen` doesn't appear to take arguments. Just call like a regular function:

```
herr_t = lib.H5Fopen()
```

**Edit:** for the version with args try:

```
lib.H5Fopen.restype = c_int
lib.H5Fopen.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_uint, c_int)
herr_t = lib.H5open(name, flags, fapl_id)
```

Just pass a string for the name and ints for the other two.

Comment: Function `H5Fopen` takes arguments: its prototype is `hid_t H5Fopen( const char *name, unsigned flags, hid_t fapl_id );` I need help to use the three arguments of this function!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't (yet) done any Hdf5 programming, but looking through [the documentation](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5F.html#File-Open), I see a few things to tell you.

What arguments you would pass to H5Fopen: the name is the filename you want to open.  flags will be either H5F_ACC_RDWR (1) or H5F_ACC_RDONLY (0).  These flags are mutually exclusive; don't or them together.  The second int is the identifier for the file access properties list.  You can set it to H5P_DEFAULT (0) for basic cases.

Here's the important thing from the documentation, though:

> **Note that H5Fopen does not create a file if it does not already exist; see H5Fcreate.**

From what you described, you don't want to use H5Fopen.  You want to use H5Fcreate.

For H5Fcreate, here's the signature

```
hid_t H5Fcreate( const char *name, unsigned flags, hid_t fcpl_id, hid_t fapl_id )
```

Name is the filename.  fcpl_id and fapl_id can both be H5P_DEFAULT, i.e. 0.  Your flags in this case are H5F_ACC_TRUNC (2) to overwrite and existing file or H5F_ACC_EXCL (4) to cause an error when you try to create an existing file.

I'm assuming you have access to find out what the constant values I listed are, but if you don't, you can look them up as I did, at http://stainless-steel.github.io/hdf5/hdf5_sys/constant.H5F_ACC_EXCL.html.

This information, combined with @101's example of how to invoke the functions should give you enough to make your initial file.